# How to send an email with attachments in Go

Tags: email, go, smtp

I have found this library and have managed to send an attachment in an empty email but not to combine text and attachments.

https://github.com/sloonz/go-mime-message

How can it be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I created [gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/) for this purpose. It supports attachments as well as multipart emails and encoding of non-ASCII characters. It is well documented and tested.

Here is an example:

```
package main

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "alex@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "bob@example.com", "cora@example.com")
    m.SetAddressHeader("Cc", "dan@example.com", "Dan")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
    m.SetBody("text/html", "Hello <b>Bob</b> and <i>Cora</i>!")
    m.Attach("/home/Alex/lolcat.jpg")

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")

    // Send the email to Bob, Cora and Dan.
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i attach a file from a URL?

Comment: @Mcbaloo To send a url you either download the file from the URL and send it as attachement, or you send the URL as a html encoded string.

Comment: gomail appears unmaintained in 2021. If you find a need to attach a file using io.Reader, this fork implements the necessary method: https://github.com/go-mail/mail.

Comment: 2023 the most active repo for this seems to be https://github.com/wneessen/go-mail. But it is frustrating that such an important problem does not have _the_ solution in Go. (In particular, not in the stdlib.)

Answer (score 23):

I ended up implementing it myself: https://github.com/scorredoira/email

Usage is very simple:

```
m := email.NewMessage("Hi", "this is the body")
m.From = "from@example.com"
m.To = []string{"to@example.com"}

err := m.Attach("picture.png")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

err = email.Send("smtp.gmail.com:587", smtp.PlainAuth("", "user", "password", "smtp.gmail.com"), m)
```

Comment: Gmail does not allow this any longer.

Comment: @qed, I've just tested with Gmail and it works fine.

Comment: @qed you need to go into your google account settings and under apps / security enable insecure app access. I highly recommend a throw-away email account for this purpose.

If you register for gmail and you're under a certain age - I think a 16 or 18 - you don't have to provide a previous email address when registering.

Comment: The **m.From** line does not work anymore because m.From only takes an mail.Address.  First there has to be a **mail.ParseAddress("from@example.com")** to return a *mail.Address, then it has to be dereferenced to be given to **m.From**.

Comment: It seems that the project has been deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use https://github.com/jordan-wright/email for email purposes.
It supports attachments.

> **Email for humans**
>
> The email package is designed to be simple to use, but flexible enough
>   so as not to be restrictive. The goal is to provide an email interface
>   for humans.
>
> The email package currently supports the following:
>
> - From, To, Bcc, and Cc fields
> - Email addresses in both "test@example.com" and "First Last " format
> - Text and HTML Message Body
> - Attachments
> - Read Receipts
> - Custom headers
> - More to come!

Answer (score 3):

Attachements in the SMTP protocol are sent using a Multipart MIME message.

So I suggest you simply

- create a `MultipartMessage`
- set your text in the fist part as a `TextMessage` (with `"Content-Type", "text/plain"`)
- add your attachements as parts using `AddPart`.

Comment: That is what I'm trying but for some reason I can't get it to work. I created an issue explaining the details here: https://github.com/sloonz/go-mime-message/issues/1

Comment: Can you please tell me which library you are referring?.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a library where you'd still have to write your own Golang code, but just a (CLI) app, I made this one: https://github.com/pepa65/mailer